# Header of AmazingListView not getting touch events

Tags: android, listview, touch-event

I am adding a header to an AmazingListView (using the [latest code](https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)):

```
mAmazingListView.setPinnedHeaderView(headerView);
```

headerView contains elements that a user should be able to interact with including a button and a HorizontalListView. When a user attempts to touch the button or scroll the HorizontalListView, the touches do not appear to reach the view as the elements do not respond.

I have tried adding headerView as a simple inflated view:

```
 View headerView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_view, mAmazingListView, false);
```

and as a fragment - by placing the embedding the fragment in a layout file, inflating that file, and fetching the fragment by its tag.

```
 headerView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_fragment_wrapper, mAmazingListView, false);
```

In neither of these cases are touches registered. If I embed the fragment directly in my view, it is able to receive touch events so I think the embedding of the view within the header of the AmazingListView is absorbing the touches at a non-desired place.

Calling setFocusable(true) on the headerView also did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid what you're trying to do is not possible using `AmazingListView`. If you look inside `AmazingListView`:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    if (mHeaderViewVisible) {
        drawChild(canvas, mHeaderView, getDrawingTime());
    }
}
```

`AmazingListView` just draws the header, it is not added to the heirarchy as an element. Therefore, it will not receive touches as expected.